Why is this reordering of sub and mul instructions helpful?
This is an example code from Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective.
short foo(short a, short b) {
    short result;
    result = b;
    while(b > 0) {
        result *= a;
        b -= a;
    }
    return result;
}

Compiling this with gcc14.2 using -O1 and -O3 gives the following assembly (godbolt)
O1
foo:
        movl    %esi, %eax
        movl    %esi, %ecx
        testw   %si, %si
        jle     .L1
.L3:
        imull   %edi, %eax
        subl    %edi, %ecx
        testw   %cx, %cx
        jg      .L3
.L1:
        ret

O3
foo:
        movl    %esi, %eax
        movl    %esi, %edx
        testw   %si, %si
        jle     .L1
.L3:
        subl    %edi, %edx
        imull   %edi, %eax
        testw   %dx, %dx
        jg      .L3
.L1:
        ret

With O3, sub comes before imul - why is this reordering helpful?

I am assuming this has to do with instruction-level parallelism, but cannot get the exact reason. Is it that performing subtraction first will allow parts of multiplication to also get done with some idle ALUs?
With respect to pipelining, is there any difference due to this reordering?


Just as you note, subl and imul can be executed in parallel (neither depends on the other), but testw does depend on subl's result (and theoretically, whether or not to use the result of the next imul depends on testw) As such, you want to complete, and therefore start, subl as soon as possible so that testw can start whether or not imul has completed.

Out-of-order exec (including across loop iterations) has a much bigger effect than instruction scheduling over this very short distance, but yes, that's presumably what GCC is optimizing for.  Semi-related: Avoid stalling pipeline by calculating conditional early - getting an input ready earlier for a macro-fused test+jcc uops is the same idea as running a test early and later branching on the flags.  (The latter is normally only viable on RISC ISAs that make flag-setting optional, unlike x86 where most integer math always writes FLAGS.)

By testing all of optimization flags which express in official documentation
I find that what cause mul and sub reordering isn't neither O1 or O3 but on O2 level of optimization
But for now still not find exact compiler flag responsible for this reordering.
In following hours I try to find It.
O2
$ make 
gcc -O2 optimize.c
gcc -O2 -S  optimize.c

.L3:
    subl    %edi, %edx
    imull   %edi, %eax
    testw   %dx, %dx
    jg  .L3

And O1
$ make 
gcc -O1 optimize.c
gcc -O1 -S  optimize.c

.L3:
    imull   %edi, %eax
    subl    %edi, %ecx
    testw   %cx, %cx
    jg  .L3


There might not be any -f switch that controls this. Some optimizations are controlled directly by the -O level.

@zwol: In this case there is: https://godbolt.org/z/8sTa675hs shows gcc -O1 -fschedule-insns does the sub earlier, plain -O1 doesn't.  -fschedule-insns2 also does it, probably since it implies -fschedule-insns (I think) plus another pass after register allocation, according to the manual.  That was my first guess for what GCC option would control it, since reordering instructions (especially without changing the logic at all) is called instruction scheduling. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_scheduling

@PeterCordes, Thanks for your comment and introduce godbolt website. I check it out GCC official documentation and tried to mixed all O1 and O2 corresponding -f flag. But when all flags are enabled no change occurred in our output. I mean reordering sub and mul.

@PeterCordes, If zwol comment correct which seems true on my test, This line on GCC documentation "-O2 turns on all optimization flags specified by -O1. It also turns on the following optimization flags:" contradicts.

@PeterCordes, Here also I enabled all flags inside O1, O2, O3
https://godbolt.org/z/GoxdGfqK8 but not change on cmd reordering.

@EsmaeelE: (almost) none of the -f optimization flags do anything if you don't enable optimization (-O with an optimization level other than the default -O0).  That's why I used -O1 -fschedule-insns to show it was the important flag.  You could try -O2 -fno-schedule-insns and see if that turns it off.  So anyway, optimization being enabled in general is something that's only controlled by -O options, but like zwol said there are some actual optimization passes that don't have their own -f option, so -Og plus all the -f options for -O2 might not equal actual -O2.

@PeterCordes, to not change operation orders I must use -O2 -fno-schedule-insns2 instead of -O2 -fno-schedule-insns.
I think documentation is wrong. When they list all corresponding flag (i.e. -f) for each O1, O2 and O3. Is my conclusion wrong?
Also I find this similar answer and bug fix for GCC. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25123408/7508077

https://godbolt.org/z/4zTzrsjWd

@EsmaeelE: Oh right, according to the manual, -O2 enables both -fschedule-insns and -fschedule-insns2.  So it makes some sense that -fno-schedule-insns wouldn't disable all scheduling.  Not sure why -O2 -fno-schedule-insns2 is sufficient to disable it, unless the no-2 option implies no-1 as well, or if that i386 GCC4.6 tuning detail of -fno-schedule-insns being off by default even at -O2 still applies in GCC14 for x86-64 (which has twice as many integer regs, as many as 32-bit ARM for example.)

If that's true for x86-64, then maybe either scheduling pass can do this optimization, but normally only the one following register allocation is done.

@PeterCordes, I find that gcc -Q -O2 --help=optimizers | grep enabled | awk '{print $1}' | grep schedule -fschedule-fusion -fschedule-insns2  O2 only enable the fschedule-insns2 optimization.

Yup, that's what I see on Godbolt for x86-64 GCC as well.  So that would explain it.  -fschedule-insns2 is the part of -O2 that's doing this, I should have said that in my first comment. Fun fact: https://godbolt.org/z/6sPsGqnrv shows that for other architectures (AArch64 and ARM32), both scheduling passes are enabled at -O2.  So the docs are correct in general, just not for i386/x86-64. Instruction scheduling is less valuable in general for x86-64 since most insns write FLAGS, and all current mainstream implementations do out-of-order exec, both of which are not the case for 32-bit ARM.
